# babel arrow functions error in node_modules

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, react-native-web

when i want build react the bellow error appear(error in node_modules):

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-video/Video.js 54:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (54:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   }
| 
>   seek = (time, tolerance = 100) => {
|     if (isNaN(time)) throw new Error('Specified time is not a number');
```

And i add this section to babel file

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    "@babel/preset-env", 
    '@babel/react',
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions"
  ]
}
```

and my webpack

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        ....
};
```

Can any one help ?

Comment: Try to include the node_module in webpack config. Like {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'',
        include: [
          resolve('src'),
          resolve('node_modules/react-native-video/'),
      }

Comment: hi , error `include: [ resolve('src'), resolve('node_modules/react-native-video/')]`

Comment: What's the error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my Webpack config is not set up to pass node_modules files to babel-loader
remove `exclude: /node_modules/,`